# 2D game, turn Player 1 to Player 2

Tags: python, trigonometry

I have a 2D game. Each player has its location(x,y) and heading(right is 0deg, up is 90deg etc.)
I need a method, to set Player1 heading towards Player2. I tried to calculate it by calculating slope -

```
slope = (player2.y - player1.y)/(player2.x - player1.x)
heading = degrees(atan(slope))
```

However it doesn´t return correct result everytime. Would you recommend me any other approach?

Comment: Have a look at `math.atan2()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are suffering from the fact that `atan(slope)` cannot deliver correct values for all directions.  This is because the slope doesn't include the direction.  A turn of 180° will leave the slope unchanged.  Mathematically, this derives from the fact that -y/-x = y/x.

You are not the first to find this out.  A traditional solution for the situation was always to look closely at the signs of the x and y values and then decide in which quadrant the result of the `atan()` should be located.

Nowadays this is done in the function with the uninspired name `atan2()`.  This receives two values (y and x) and does all that is required to find out the proper direction angle in the range (-180°, +180°], given as radians, so it is the range (-pi, +pi].